# match pattern to its counterpart from a list of patterns

Tags: python, regex, string, replace

In Python, I want to have a pair like this:

patterns:

```
abc, def
ghi, jkl
mno, xyz
```

The idea is: given a string, I want to search for occurrence of any of the pattern p from patterns and when I find a match, I would like to subsititute it with its counterpart.

For example:

- this is an abcwer string
- this is an `def`wer string `(replaced string)`
- lot of matches together abc-ghi-mno
- lot of matches together `def-jkl-xyz` `(replaced string)`

Uptil now, I was replacing pattern matches with empty string and here is how I was doing this:

```
regExps = [ re.compile(re.escape(p), re.IGNORECASE) for p in patterns ]

def cleanseName(dirName, name):
# please ignore dirName here since I have just put here a snippet of the code
    old = name
    new = ""
    for regExp in regExps:
        if regExp.search(old):
            new = regExp.sub("", old).strip()
            old = new
    if new != "":
        new = old
        print("replaced string: %s" % new)
```

So, how can i substitute for a pair of strings here ? What is the `pythonic` way of doing this ?

Answer (score 2):

You can support overlapping strings by using the function-accepting version of `re.sub`:

```
import re

substitutions = {
    "abc": "def",
    "def": "ghi",
    "ghi": "jkl",
    "jkl": "mno",
    "mno": "pqr"
}

def match_to_substitution(match):
    return substitutions[match.group()]

string = "abc def ghi jkl mno"

substitute_finder = re.compile("|".join(map(re.escape, substitutions)))

substitute_finder.sub(match_to_substitution, string)
#>>> 'def ghi jkl mno pqr'
```

Comment: I want to make sure I understand this correctly: 1. compile all the substitution paired strings (and escape them) into a pattern. 2. for every match in string, call match_to_substitution 3. I don't understand how substitutions[match.group()] works here

Comment: @brainydexter When `re.sub` finds a match, if its substitution argument is callable it will call it with the match. So I get the string matched using `match.group()` and then get the thing to replace with using `substitutions[...]`.

Answer (score 0):

```
patterns = [('abc','def'),('ghi','jkl'),('mno','xyz')]

def cleanse_name(name, patterns):
    for from_,to in patterns:
        name = re.sub(re.escape(from_), to, name, flags=re.I)
    print(name)

cleanse_name("abcghimno Smith", patterns)
# defjklxyz Smith
```

Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: This will have problems if substitutions can themselves be substituted (aka. `"ab".replace("a", "b").replace("b", "c")`).

Comment: @veedrac yes but there's no great way to handle that :(